Navigation link cannot be activated
I am working on combining two feeds in the same view. They are held inside a ZStack enclosed by a NavigationStack. The issue arises when clicking on the tab bar item to navigate to the message view, which works fine. However, when coming back and clicking on a NavigationLink to navigate to a user profile page, this results in issues:
A NavigationLink is presenting a value of type "User," but there is no matching NavigationDestination declaration visible from the location of the link. The link cannot be activated.
Note: Links search for destinations in any surrounding NavigationStack, then within the same column of a NavigationSplitView.
Here is the main view:
struct Feed: View {
    @State private var path: NavigationPath = NavigationPath()
    @State private var selectedView = "Events"
    private let options = ["Events", "Posts"]
    @State private var show = false
    @State private var showNewTweetView = false
    @State private var messageCount: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            ZStack{
                EventFeed(path: $path).opacity(selectedView == "Posts" ? 0 : 1)
            }
            
            .navigationDestination(for: User.self, destination: { result in
                SearchableUserProfile(user: result, path: $path)
            })
        
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { result in

                    ChatChannelView(
                        viewFactory: CustomUIFactory.shared,
                        channelController: ChatManager.shared.client.channelController(
                            for: try! ChannelId(cid: result),
                            messageOrdering: .topToBottom
                        )
                    )
                    .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Home")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    Picker("Select View", selection: $selectedView) {
                        ForEach(options, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0)
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: MessageView()) {
                        VStack{
                            Image(systemName: "ellipsis.message")
                                .font(.title)
                            Text(messageCount)
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
          
            
        }
    }
}

Here is the Event Feed view which is displayed inside the the Feed View:
struct EventFeed: View {
    @State private var show = false
    @State private var showNewTweetView = false
    @State private var didFinishSetup = false
    @EnvironmentObject var newEventViewModel: EventPostViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel : EventFeedViewModel
    @State private var showComments = false
    init(path: Binding<NavigationPath>){
        UIScrollView.appearance().decelerationRate = .fast
        self._path = path
    }
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            LazyVStack(spacing: 40){
                ForEach(viewModel.EventPost) { event in
                    EventFeedPost( event: event).onTapGesture {
                    }
                    Divider()
                }
            }.padding(.top,8)
        }
    
}


Here is where the navigation occus when clicking on a event feed item to navigate to a user profile:
struct EventFeedPost: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myEventsViewModel : MyEventFeedViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var localNotificationManger: LocalNotificationManager
    @State private var showEventDetails = false
    @State private var showComments = false
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: EventFeedCellViewModel
    @State private var showButtons = false
    private var event: Event{
        return viewModel.event
    }
    
    private var isGoing: Bool{
        return event.isGoing ?? false
    }
    
    init(event: Event){
        self.viewModel = EventFeedCellViewModel(event: event)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack{
                if let user = event.user{
                    HStack{
                        NavigationLink(value: user) {
                            CircularProfileImageVIew(user: user, size: .medium)
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                            Text(event.user?.fullname ?? "")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                        }
}
}


MessageView contains a customUI factory model from getstream.io that I didn't really customize. I added no navigation stack besides FeedView.
